# Raspberry pi 3 cpuinfo ARMv7

Tags: arm, raspberry-pi, raspbian, raspberry-pi3

I just installed last raspbian on my pi 3.
lscpu tells me that my cpu model is ARMv7 but it should be ARMv8 (according to rpi 3 specs).
Did I buy a fake card ?

Comment: No, it's just running a 32-bit v7 kernel, is all.

Answer (score 1):

It's running 32 bit so it reports v7.

The distro isn't 64bit yet (from what I read a week ago), when it is, it'll report v8.